# How to pull all staffNames from Department in AD and place in a dropdown?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ldap

Help, I am wondering how to get all staffNames from a Department and then bind this into a dropdown? Here is my code to find one record but I want all results?

```
        string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ADConnection"].ToString();

        DirectorySearcher dssearch = new DirectorySearcher(connection);
        dssearch.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + current_User + ")";
        SearchResult sresult = dssearch.FindOne();
        DirectoryEntry dsresult = sresult.GetDirectoryEntry();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call *FindAll()* instead of *FindOne()* since you want ALL staff-names, and use *SearchResultCollection* instead of *SearchResult* so you can hold more than ONE record, then you can bind the results to a dropdown using a foreach:

**C# Code-Behind:**

```
string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ADConnection"].ToString();

DirectorySearcher dssearch = new DirectorySearcher(connection);
dssearch.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Person))";
dssearch.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + current_User + ")";

SearchResultCollection searchResult = dssearch.FindAll();

foreach (SearchResult srUSers in searchResult)
{
    DirectoryEntry de = srUsers.GetDirectoryEntry();
    dropDownList1.Items.Add(de.Name.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thats great but I was also wondering how to just get each users given name StaffName as it appears as  CN=Joe Bloggs 111111. I was wondering how to get rid of the canonical cn bit and also is there anyway to order alphabetically? cheers!

Comment: what is the output of de.Name.ToString()?

Comment: It goes into the dropdown as cn=Joe Bloggs 111111 (samAccountName). I am trying to get all the names in a department into a drop down using the code:

Comment: string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ADConnection"].ToString();

            DirectorySearcher dssearch = new DirectorySearcher(connection);
            dssearch.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=user))";
            dssearch.Filter = "(Department=" + "DFP" + ")";


            SearchResultCollection searchResult = dssearch.FindAll();

            foreach (SearchResult srUsers in searchResult)
            {
                DirectoryEntry de = srUsers.GetDirectoryEntry();
              
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(de.Name.ToString());

            }